# Excel 2010 links work for me but not for other people

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, links

We have a large data file in Excel 2010. Several other files have data linked from that file.  If the data file gets modified, the other files get automatically updated.  This works when I do it on my computer, but other users are getting a popup to continue or edit links.  If they choose 'Continue', the links don't update. If they choose 'Edit Links', they get 'Error: source not found'.

Any idea why it works for me but not for anyone else?

Answer (score 1):

The most obvious answer is that the linked files are only on your computer or are only accessible from your computer.  Check this by trying to open one of the linked files on another user's machine.

Assuming the files are on the network, then it could be because your network drives are mapped differently to the other users and excel can find `H:\Network\Spreadsheets\myFile.xlsx` from your machine, but other users have that network location mapped to `I:\` drive.

In either event, the other users should be able to follow where excel thinks the links are which will give you more clues as to what is causing the problem.  This [support page](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/826921) may help.